# Is it possible when filling in an attribute to get a pop up where you can pick an object from another layer and choose wich attribute to copy from it

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

When asked to fill in an attribute from an object, I want to click on another object from another layer and choose which attribute I want to put in.

Other methods, tips and tricks to achieve the same are also welcome...

Comment: This is just an idea, I haven't tested it. What if you create a virtual layer that includes the layer you're editing and all the layers you want to copy attributes from. Then maybe you can select both features and use "merge attributes" to copy attributes from one feature to the other.

Comment: The Attribute painter plugin, "Plugin for easy replication of attributes values between features," sounds like it does what you want. Available in QGIS 3.0, not sure about earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

If both features share some spatial extent, you can use the vector data management tools -> join attributes by location. Or you could give out unique IDs which match for source and target feature and later do some SQL-data management.

Comment: I know that I can use "join attributes by location", that's what I intent to do if I dont find another solution. I want to try to get the data when mapping an object and not afterwards. Say you have a layer1 with the fields A, B and C and a layer2 with the fields A, D and E. When I map an object on layer1 I want him to fill in field A
automatically with A from layer2 by a matching field (join) or by manual clicking on the object. How awsome would it be to take over some of the attributes from another object in another layer by clicking on the object.